# Rotate a child node in spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a node that I need to rotate, however as it is a child node whenever I rotate it changes size. This is because it is created with a y scale value of 0.7693. I have tried creating a algorithm to manipulate the x and y scale based on the z rotation, but nothing works. Is their anyway to do this?

edit: I have found that statically changing the x and y scales does not work here is my code for that:

```
var ScaleDir: CGFloat = 1
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
        let turnAngle:Double = 1
        startWheel.zRotation = startWheel.zRotation + CGFloat(turnAngle / (180/Double.pi))
        if startWheel.zRotation*(180/CGFloat.pi) >= 360{
            startWheel.zRotation = startWheel.zRotation - (360/(180/CGFloat.pi))
        }
        startWheel.yScale = startWheel.yScale + (CGFloat((1 - 0.7693) / Double(90/turnAngle)) * ScaleDir)
        startWheel.xScale = startWheel.xScale - (CGFloat((1 - 0.7693) / Double(90/turnAngle)) * ScaleDir)
        if startWheel.yScale >= 1 || startWheel.xScale >= 1{
            ScaleDir = ScaleDir * -1
        }
}
```

I have realized the problem. The automatically assigned Yscale moves with the rotating node however the ovular shape that is created by the spriteKit scaling system does not and stays vertical.

Here is what my problem looks like:

[image: As you can see it is not a circle.]

Comment: Have you tried undoing the yScale, rotating and then reapplying the yScale?

Comment: That does not work here is what I tried  `let turnAngle:Double = 1
            startWheel.yScale = 1
            startWheel.xScale = 1
            startWheel.zRotation = startWheel.zRotation + CGFloat(turnAngle / (180/Double.pi))
            startWheel.yScale = 0.7693
            startWheel.xScale = 1`

Comment: @DaveWeston Is there any other way?

Comment: I'm away from my computer right now, but I can play with this a little later tonight. No promises. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the parent node had a y scale and this was causing all of the problems, as soon as I removed the y-scale and changed it back to 1 everything started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

If the scale is applied after the rotation, then you want to use `sin` on the angle to figure out the Y component and `cos` to figure out the X.

But, I would try giving this node a dummy parent node and rotate that.

Comment: I tried what I think you mean by a dummy parent node, however it had the same effect. On the other hand can you be more specific about how you could use sin and cos to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Did you NOT set scale on the dummy parent node (just rotation?)  Set rotation on the parent and scale on the child

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple code I was using in a playground to try to duplicate what you described in your question. I tried manipulating the yScale and rotation of various elements in the setup but nothing seemed to reproduce the undesired behavior. Have I reasonably replicated your setup, or am I missing something?

```
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

public class GameScene: SKScene {
    let node: SKNode

    init(nodeToRotate: SKNode) {
        self.node = nodeToRotate
        super.init(size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 400))
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    public override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        let turnAngle = 9.0
        node.zRotation = node.zRotation + CGFloat(turnAngle / (180.0/Double.pi))
    }
}

let square = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 80, height: 80))
square.fillColor = .purple
square.strokeColor = .purple
square.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 200)

let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 30)
circle.fillColor = .orange
circle.strokeColor = .orange
circle.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
circle.yScale = 0.7
square.addChild(circle)

let scene = GameScene(nodeToRotate: square)
scene.addChild(square)

let view = SKView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 400)))
view.presentScene(scene)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: I updated my question with a picture of my problem. As you can see the rotating color wheel is the sprite I would like to rotate, some more information on that sprite: It is the parent node of 4 shape nodes. It is the child node of a Sprite node. When anything is created in this sprite node it is automatically assigned a yScale of 0.7693, so that it looks like a circle(Without this y Scale it looks like an Oval). I believe that the problem is that when I rotate the node the y scale rotates with it, yet the elongated side created by the SpriteKit scale system does not rotate with the sprite.